# Creating PDF files with Html2ps/Html2pdf in CakePHP2.0 - Blank pdf

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am using Html2pdf component in cakephp 2.0 . Its working fine in my local when I move to server it generating the Blank pdf file. i try to debug it shows following error message 
I gave 777 permission on all the necessary folders..

Cannot open http://200.192.34.44/reports/create [APP/Vendor/html2ps/fetcher.url.class.php, line 94]

Any one have idea ??

I am using IP address so that its not working, i need solution for this

Comment: had a similar issue, check that the url you are getting your info from isn't escaped, eg.: `$Pdf->process(Router::url('/', true))); ` and NOT `$Pdf->process( urlencode(Router::url('/', true)) )); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found that we need to make

> **"allow_url_fopen"  "ON"**
>
> Other options you need to check the following:

1. Check **fsocket** function working fine in your server
2. Check Port numbers are enabled properly
3. If its is a Linux server and you have ssh just use wget and check the
   url is working fine on the same server

   in php.ini

now its working fine